# send array of array to post API in flutter

Tags: arrays, json, laravel, flutter, api

I have an API that needed me sending an array of array to the backend the form of request body is

```
{
    "pharmacy_id" : 15,
    "medicines": [{"medicine_id": 500, "amount": 2},{"medicine_id": 520, "amount": 5}],
    "latitude" : 24.2594,
    "longitude" : 27.654
}
```

I thought that is a list of map so I make it as `List<<Map<String,dynamic>>`
and the result was

`[{"medicine_id": 500, "amount": 2},{"medicine_id": 520, "amount": 5}]`

but the response come as follow

```
value body is : {"message":"The given data was invalid.","errors":{"medicines":["The medicines must be an array."]}}
value.reasonPhrase is : Unprocessable Content
value.statusCode is : 422
```

so my question is : how to send this data and in which form I should make it in ?

my API post Function

```
Future<void> cartOrder({required String pharmacy_id,required int pharmID, required List<Map<String,dynamic>> medicines, String? coupon, required BuildContext context}) async{
    emit(HomeGetAboutUsLoadingState());
    await http.post(
        Uri.parse('${api}order/store'),
        body:{
          'pharmacy_id': pharmacy_id,
          'medicines': medicines,
          'latitude': latitude,
          'longitude': longitude,
          'coupon': coupon
        }, headers: {'Accept': 'application/json', 'Authorization' : 'Bearer ${CacheHelper.getData(key: 'token')}'
    }).then((value){
      oneOrderModel = OneOrderModel.fromJson(jsonDecode(value.body));
      print("value body is : ${value.body}");
      print("oneOrderModel is $oneOrderModel");
      print("value.reasonPhrase is : ${value.reasonPhrase}");
      print("value.statusCode is : ${value.statusCode}");
      print("cartOrder value is : $value");
      navigateFinalTo(context,const HomeDrawer());
      print("cart order value is : $value");
      print("cart order success");
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "تم إرسال طلبك بنجاح");
      print("load user order");
      UserOrders();
      print("user order loaded");
      int index = 0;
      myItems.forEach((element) {
        deleteRowCart(id: pharmID, index: index);
        index++;
      });
      print("my list item is empty now");
      emit(HomeGetAboutUsSuccessState());
    }).catchError((error){
      print("cart order error is : $error");
      emit(HomeGetAboutUsErrorState());
    });
  }
```

the list of medicines and thier amount is

````
var extractMap = cubit.myItems.map((element) => Map.fromEntries([
MapEntry('medicine_id', element['medicineID']),
MapEntry('amount', element['quantity']),])).toList();
print("my order items is : $extractMap");
extractMap.isNotEmpty ?
cubit.cartOrder(context: context,
pharmID: cubit.onePharmacyModel!.data!.id!.toInt(),
pharmacy_id: cubit.onePharmacyModel!.data!.id!.toString(),
medicines: extractMap,
coupon: codeController.text.toString()
): Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "cart is empty");
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this:

```
Future<void> cartOrder({required String pharmacy_id,required int pharmID, required List<Map<String,dynamic>> medicines, String? coupon, required BuildContext context}) async{
    emit(HomeGetAboutUsLoadingState());
    await http.post(
        Uri.parse('${api}order/store'),
        body:json.encode({
          'pharmacy_id': pharmacy_id,
          'medicines': medicines,
          'latitude': latitude,
          'longitude': longitude,
          'coupon': coupon
        }), headers: {'Accept': 'application/json', 'Authorization' : 'Bearer ${CacheHelper.getData(key: 'token')}'
    })
......
```